# In code first "ies" (plural) is mandatory

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

Here im trying to get data from database using code-first but if I have a tabel Like `Country`, like this:

```
 public class Country
 {
     public int id { get; set; }    
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

contextdb

```
 public class ContextDb: DbContext
 {
     public ContextDb() { }
     public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
     ...
  }
```

when I implements as `Countrys` its throwing an error:

> `Countries` not have dbo

Comment: You should implement it as `Countries` ;-)

Comment: but in my database i have table name as Country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually we use plurals in the DbContext like this:

```
public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

EF uses an `auto plural` convention, so your entity

```
 public class Country
```

will translate to a datatable `[dbo].[Countries]` in your database.

If you want to explicitly override the name of the table in the database you can use the following attribute.

```
[Table("YourNameHere")]
public class Country
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I think there is a mixup in this logic somewhere in your code.

Alternativly you can also put your table in a differnt `schema` if you like:

```
[Table("YourNameHere", Schema = "YourSchemaNameHere")]
public class Country
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Beware with renaming the schema though, I have experienced that some migrations will break because to database index names are not always handled correctly.

**note**

See @Wiktor Zychla 's solution to disable the plural conventions on the whole context.

Comment: Tahnk u soo much Mr.Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Please try to make it explicit which specific table you want for this particular type

```
public class ContextDb : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().ToTable("Country");
    }

    public ContextDb() { }
    public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
}
```

As an alternative, you can turn off the pluralizing convention

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```

Another option, as mentioned in Stefan's answer, is to have an attribute over your model class (which makes the class "not-that-POCO-anymore" but technically is perfectly valid).

Comment: Good point about the `non-poco` part, I never considered that one. Although I do tend to keep my domain-models poco.